# Two XML field on one line with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, xml, debugging, document.write, getelementsbytagname

I must say I'm no programmer and just stepping in at the last minute to help with a live event hosted on our website. Using XML files, we're trying to have two «getElementsByTagName» on the same table line. And we can't. I've seen a similar thread, but I didn't understand the coding.

**Here's part of mine:**

```
document.write("<table border='0' bgcolor='#CCCCCC' width='520' cellpadding='4'     cellspacing='4' color='#003333'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Root");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Subroot");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Subroot2");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
   document.write("<tr><td align='left'><font color='#333333'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</font></td><td align='left'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td><td align='right'>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Adress")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</td></tr>");
 }
```

From what I've read on this site so far, I take it document.write might irritate a few, but it's the only way I knew to get it up and running in a short period of time.

Basically, I'm trying to get another XML field, to show up in the script, beside the "Name".

Thanks!

Comment: if you mean in same table cell just add the `nodeValue` right after the name one and before the next `"</font></td><td align='left'>"`. Otherwise not sure what you are asking

Comment: Yes, I meant in the same table cell, sorry. In the XML file, I have "Name", "Phone", "Adress" and "FirstName" under "Subroot2". I'm trying to add the "FirstName" TagName besides "Name", on the same table cell.

Comment: should work just putting it on next line in code after name...no? add string `"&nbsp;"` to create a space also...stands for `non breaking space`

Comment: That's what I thought... But the "phone" and "adress" TagName disappear from the table or both go to the far right when I add:
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("FirstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Comment: How would I put a comma between "Name" and "FirstName" nodeValue?

Comment: `document.write(", "+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name").....)` . Anything in quotes is a string and you concatenate strings together with `+`.....string will be `comma space`

Comment: Great, it's working!! I just don't get where to add string "&nbsp;" in the code?

Comment: use plus sign to add it where you want a space

Answer (score 1):

> document.write(", "+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name").....) .
>
> Anything in quotes is a string and you concatenate strings together with +
>
> .....string will be comma space
>
> use plus sign to add it where you want a space